# Restricting contractor programmers to specific sections of the code?

Tags: azure-devops

Need a dashboard to control software contractor access to our codebase as we expand our extraction of information from medical records to more platforms, sources and formats. Want to open a window that lets them build "rooms" without leaving the doors wide open to take everything.

So we contract out for a user interface for say Medical Event review and the programmer only gets access to the automatically generated libraries and documentation for using our libraries, without gaining access to the source code. Then when their job is done we can close out their code and documentation access from a single place. If we need to open up specific module access we have a single spot to control all aspects of this access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is not a dashboard in azure devops to achieve this currently. If you are hosting your source code in Azure repo. You can only control user's access permission to Repo level. Azure repo does not have the feature to control the source code access permission in branches or files level.

So as a workaround you can move those contents that the software contractor can access in a new azure repo. You can allow the software contractor's to only access this new repo. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions) to set azure repo permission for groups/users.

Another possible workaround is to use other tools (eg.Google Drive) which can control the access permission on files level.

However, you can also [submit a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click **Suggest a feature** and choose **Azure Devops**) to Microsoft development team. Hope they will consider implementing this feature in the feature sprints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you need to develop a branching strategy in Azure Repos (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops) to break out the code you want the contractors to be able to work with in a feature branch and only grant them access to that specific feature branch, then use a pull request to integrate the feature branch into the master repo.